# $(catkin_LIBRARIES): no such files or directory

Tags: catkin-make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I've created 2 packages and catkin_make results in twice the error above. The only dependencies in both CMakeList.txt and packages.xml are rospy, roscpp and std_msgs which are there. In $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH, the ROS path is present, but not the path to my newly created packages. Is this a necessity? Any help or hints is appreciated.

Thanks

hvn

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/240383/$(catkin_libraries):-no-such-files-or-directory/) by [hvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3729/hvn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 72 on 2016-07-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) on 2016-07-26**:
Can you post your CMakeList.txt, and ROS environment variable :) ?

**Comment by [hvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3729/hvn/) on 2016-08-01**:
Thanks for your response. William's answer solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe you want to do `${catkin_LIBRARIES}`, with `{}` rather than `()`.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2016-07-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3729/hvn/) on 2016-08-01**:
Thank you. This did the trick.